# Is there a difference between the following similar statements in c++?

Tags: c++, pointers

group one:

```
char *pt[10]={}
char  pt[10]={}
```

group two:

```
char* pt
char  *pt
```

where are the differences between the above groups? Which is preferred one?

Comment: 1) A lot. 2) None of them.

Comment: @0x499602D2 I think he probably meant the difference between the two in group 1 and the difference between the two in group 2...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `char *pt[10]={}` is an array of pointers to `char`
- `char pt[10]={}` is an array of `char`.

---

In the second group...

There is no difference between `char* pt` and `char *pt`, but for readability and to avoid confusion, you're probably best of using `char *pt`.  They both create a single pointer to a `char`.  However, consider the following:

```
char* pt, c;
```

In this case, `pt` is a pointer to a `char`, while `c` is simply a regular `char` variable.  `char*` doesn't make every following variable a `char pointer`.  So as I said, for readability and to avoid confusing yourself, the following is probably better:

```
char *pt, c;
```

This is identical to the above example in what it actually accomplishes, but it's harder to misinterpret this as two pointers.  Although best practice may honestly be to just declare them on separate lines.

Comment: You should probably point out `std::string` and `std::vector<std::string>` and how it is preferable to a char array or an array of `char*`.

Comment: That's not really what the question is about.  The question is about pointers.  For all we know, he just randomly picked `char` as the data type for the example...